# How do I convert a simple jni example from Cmake to ndk-build?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I'm a long time programmer but new to Android Studio. I have inherited some existing JNI library code intended to be run with ndk-build that already has its Android.mk file. It would be nice to reuse that. When I opened a new project with Android Studio and set the C++ support flag, it set itself up to use CMake instead of ndk-build. The documentation for Android Studio says both are available so I decided to try a simple test to see if I had found all the places that needed to change. It was a complete fail with error messages that seem to lead nowhere.

To recreate, create a new project ProjTest2 with Android Studio and check the Include C++ Support box. Accept the default Phone and Tablet form factor with a Minimum SDK of API 16: Android 4.1. Choose the Empty Activity. Accept the default Activity and Layout names. Accept the default Toolchain and do not check the boxes for Exceptions Support or Runtime. Run program, select device Android Emulator Nexus_5_API_24:5554. All is well; get message Hello from C++ on emulator screen.

Attempt to change to ndk-build. Open build.grade file for Module:app. Replace lines:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

with:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "jni/Android.mk"
    }
}
```

Create a new folder jni in the directory ProjTest2/app. Create the file Android.mk in that folder with the following content:

```
# A simple test for the minimal standard C++ library
#

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := native-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The build now fails claiming that it cannot find the target of #include <string> and that it cannot resolve the container 'std'. I find that I can clear the IDE error flags by adding LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += C:\Users\JWC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include to the Android.mk file but the resulting make still fails when it cannot find some of the sub-includes from <string>.

Did I miss something simple, or is this just not as easy as it seems it should be?

Edit:

Also needs file:

```
# Application.mk

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
APP_OPTIM := release

APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake defaults to using the `gnustl_static` STL, whereas ndk-build defaults to using none.

Add the following to your project:

jni/Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

There are a handful of these available. `gnustl_static` will match the cmake use, but you can see other choices in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html).

Comment: Adding that line seems to have no effect. The include and the class are still undefined. I put the line in immediately after the include $(CLEAR_VARS) line. Is the placement important?

Comment: As my answer says, it's supposed to go in Application.mk.

Comment: Yes, I see. I missed Application.mk altogether. Adding the file noted in the edit of the original question fixed it. Thanks.